# Как устанавливать Ubuntu автоматически?

Tags: установка, ubuntu

Для Windows есть вариант установки (unattended install), когда все опции, которые нужно выбирать вручную во время самого процесса установки в разных меню, можно задать в виде ключей командной строки или в виде файла настроек.

Поскольку Ubuntu сейчас достаточно широко используется и на серверах, наверняка реализован подобный подход к установке и для нее. Как это делается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите здесь: [automating the installation using preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/installation-guide/i386/appendix-preseed.html).

> Автоматизация обеспечивает способ выбора ответов на вопросы, задаваемые во время процесса установки, без необходимости вручную вводить ответы в то время, как установка работает. Это дает возможность автоматизации наиболее типичных установок, а также предоставляет дополнительные возможности, которые недоступны во время обычной установки.

А также [автоматическая преднастроенная установка Ubuntu: isolinux и preseed](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/ubuntu/104029/).
Еще для Windows есть установщик wubi. Подробная информация доступна по [ссылке](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_ubuntu_%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_windows).